# How to replace only SOME missing data

Tags: missing-data

I have two types of missing data (non-responses and "Don't know or does not apply") and I want to replace only the non-responses (with mean or by using EM or by using Multiple Imputation) and to see if this is a good solution. How can this be done in SPSS? Even in the simplest case, when replacing missing values with mean for example, I can't find a way to impute only some of the missing data, in this case the non-responses?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution to your problem is to not to treat "don't know" as missing but a separate data type in itself. By this I mean if you currently have 3 categories, with NA, make it four categories and NA where category 4 is "don't know". After this you can use the standard EM methods

There are 2 points I want to make in connection with @Rociante's reply.

1) I think he/she means f(i) = 0.5*(f(i-1) + f(i+1)). I would not recommend taking the average of the previous and the next in general because a) you do not know that consecutive points are related and b) you seem to have categorical types in which case this does not make sense anyways. If you must, use the MLE estimate.

2) Be very careful while dealing with NULLs in different langauges. Go through the documentation carefully when implementing the pseudo-code. You cannot say for example i=='NULL' in python and in fact most languages will not allow it (not sure of SPSS). Most languages treat NULL as its own type which can be anything. In python you would say

try:

```
i = i + 0
```

except:

and in R you could use is.na(..)

Comment: By making "Don't know/Does not apply" a category in itself, do you mean to assign a numeric value to this type of answers and then use it in EM (so to impute also with "Don't know/Does not apply")? Wouldn't the results differ depending on the value that I would assing?

Comment: Depends on how the other categories are assigned. If the value you assign to the "don't know" entry is simply a LABEL and does not hold any numerical significance it will impute values as 1/2/3/"don't know". Make sure you chose the right type of EM imputation technique

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunatelly, it seems that it is not possible to assing just a label and not a numerical value as well for "Don't know", as long as a variable is defined as numeric (in SPSS).

Comment: Im sorry, I have not worked in SPSS before though I will be very surprised if SPSS does not have that option. Check things having the keyword factor in it. For R the command would as be as.factor

Comment: Maybe it has but so far I wasn't able to find it. Could you be more specific about the keyword "factor"? Where should I look for it? I think it's easier to treat "Do not know/Does not apply" as missing data than as another category.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to generalize my response instead of making it SPSS-specific (as that's probably against the forum rules). You need to write a loop that goes through your data set. This loop goes through all the values in your data set and replaces the null with the average of the values that come immediately before(i-1) and immediately after (i+1) the null (i.e. non-response). If your data set is small enough, you can also do the calculation manually instead of writing the loop. The pseudo-code is:

```
for (i=2:n)
{
  if(i=="null")
  {
   i = ((i-1)+(i+1))/2
  }
  else
  { 
    i++
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I do not know how to write code. Are you suggesting that the average is calculated based only on the values thae are just before and after the non-response? I have some scales with different items and I need to impute with the average resulted at the level of each item. Thank you!

Comment: The calculation depends on what kind of imputation you want to do. I chose the simplest algorithm of taking the average of the values that flank the missing one because that's the easiest one to illustrate in code rather than MLE. If you want another imputation method that may be more appropriate to your discipline, obviously use that instead of the average. To learn how to write a loop in SPSS specifically, either check the help manual or pose the question on Stackoverflow - they help with programming questions. 1/2

Comment: 2/2  The other option is to do this in R, which has ready-made packages for imputation (not just the simple one I illustrated above).

Comment: Also, I think you need to be careful when you say that the data is missing. If the person said "don't know" or "not apply", then the cell should have some value there, like "n/a" instead of just being blank. In other words, the blank cells should be the only ones that are missing data and for which you want to impute.